# IIS URL rewrite rule from http to https for sub-domain

Tags: iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have tried multiple IIS rewrite rules to redirect my sub-domain to https.
Question: How do I make my subdomain `http://test.example.com` to redirect to `https://test.example.com`. To provide more information the subdomain is not a folder but isolated website. Below rule didn't work for me.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

FYI: It works fine at my production website because there I could write a condition for `www.`.

Comment: Where did you put the rewrite rule? To make it effective to more than one site, it must be at server level.

Comment: @LexLi: I put it at the root web.config of subdomain site i.e `test.example.com` because `example.com` is another site.

Comment: Use FRT as it prints more info, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules